# Wireless card keeps connecting then disconnecting

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, ipv6, broadcom

I have a Broadcom BCM43142 chip, it works normally as of Debian 9. But after upgrading to Debian 10, it displays this weird behavior of automatically disconnecting from WiFi, reconnecting successfully for 3 seconds, disconnecting and the cycle keeps continuing. It has lead to websites loading really slow or failed to load at all. Here is a snippet of `sudo dmesg` :

```
[ 1073.310482] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 1107.065818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 1107.065852] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
[ 1145.315969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready
[ 1145.316005] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
```

And here is what happens when I run `iwconfig` twice:

```
$ sudo iwconfig
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-LINK_754E"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz 
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

$ sudo iwconfig
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

It can be seen that wlp6s0 was connected to my wifi then suddenly dropped off for no obvious reasons.

The problem is not because of the router or the chip because I dual boot with Windows and it works normally. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Edited (Output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3`):

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Did you install [broadcom-sta-dkms](https://packages.debian.org/buster/broadcom-sta-dkms)? See [https://wiki.debian.org/wl](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) for instructions and also the "frequent disconnection issue" in [Known Issues](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Known_Issues).

Comment: @Freddy I already had it, otherwise I would not have wlp6sp be available. I have also tried to remove and reinstall it as well but the problem still persists.

Comment: Ok, does it get better if you turn off the power management with `iwconfig wlp6sp power off`?

Comment: No, I have tried that as well. You can see from my  post above that when I ran iwconfig power management was off.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Sorry, didn't see that :)

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks, I have added the output of the command in the post above.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I ran `journalctl -xe` and noticed that hostapd was disabling wlp6s0. Purging hostapd with `sudo apt autoremove --purge hostapd` solved the problem.